# Batch file - finding a string after a space in a text file

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I wonder if someone can help me with this?

I need a way in a batch file to assign a variable to a string in a text file.

My text file looks like below (a user name - a space - then a postcode):

User1 postcode
User2 postcode
User3 postcode
User3 postcode

Basically I know I can use the findstr command to search for the user but I need some way to get findstr to look at the postcode entry for that user then assign it to a variable in the batch file. I'm sure there must be a way to make findstr find the space after the user and then look at the postcode.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (filename.txt) do if %1 == %%a set postcode=%%b & goto found
echo User name not found!
goto :eof
:found
```

Previous Batch file seek for the user name given in the first parameter, and assign the postcode to "postcode" variable.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you ever wanted to know about string manipulation from batch files.

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Now the question is does it have to be a batch file for any particular reason?